# What's happening when server.accept()

Tags: java, sockets

I'm trying to write a simple Java chat application in Server/Client.

I'm confusing in below method at `server.accept()` :

```
private void waitForConnection() throws IOException {
    showMessage("Waiting for someone to connect... \n");

    // `connection` is an instance of `java.net.Socket` 
    // `server` is an instance of `java.net.ServerSocket`
    connection = server.accept();
    showMessage("Now connected to " + connection.getInetAddress().getHostName());
}
```

Please tell me `connection` is equal to what?

And also `server.accept()` returns what?

Any helps would be awesome.

Comment: Well, show the type of `server`, then we might tell what `accept` method is returning (though it probably is a `Socket`.

Comment: @HamedKamrava `server.accept()` is a block, which means your program will stop in until a client connects. Only when a client connects to your server your code will resume running.

Comment: @Darkhogg,@Matthias I mentioned that in commented-line that `server` is an instance of `ServerSocket`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you do connections between two systems then you require a socket.

Socket of one system is connected with socket of another system. Both these sockets are connected via I/O stream. you can write to this stream and can read from this stream.

One system serves as server and another system serves as client .

As socket is combination of port no. and IP so server open its port no. and client try to connect with the server's IP and port no.

For connection to be maid the server accepts the incoming socket using `accept()` function. `accept()` function  **returns a local socket which is connected to another socket at the client..**

`accept()` waits until a client socket  arrives.

Comment: It doesn't return 'the socket of client system'. It returns a local socket which is connected to another socket at the client.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your `server` variable is a `java.net.ServerSocket` then the `accept()` method returns a `java.net.Socket` object.

From the returned `Socket` object, you have access to both the `InputStream` and `OutputStream` to read from and write to the connected client.

Answer (score 2):

Your program should halt until a client connects. That's what the line `connection = server.accept();` does. Returning type is a type of `Socket`, too.

That's the "connection" to your client, you can read from and write to.

Check [this](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/socket-140484.html) and [that](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/) site to read more about network programming in Java.